# Entity Framework Not Refreshing Correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hey I have a problem with entity framework and was wondering has anyone else encountered this problem. I have edited my stored procedure to now include the course.code column and also group by it. However the problem now is when I try update the model from database I still get no confirmation that is there. When I look at the code there is still no get/set method for this new value. I am correct in thinking entity framework should automatically generate this code for me?

Anyways I have tried using the custom tool on both of the .tt files with no luck. I have tried updating model from database. I have tried deleting the resultset.cs associated and finally I tried deleting the entity framework folder and restoring again from svn but still no luck. If anyone out there has encountered a similar problem and figured it out I would be forever in your debth. I am trying to add this new available field into a telerick report and so far I am having no luck. I have included the part of the stored procedure I have altered.Thanks very much in advance.

```
SELECT s.number as studentNumber, 
        s.last_name as studentLastName, 
        s.first_name as studentFirstName, 
        replace(h.name,'/',char(160) + '/' + char(160)) as homeroomName, 
        c.name as courseName,
        **c.Code as courseCode,**
        ISNULL(o.priceaspurchased, i.price) as Total,
```

Comment: If you are doing database first, you need to update the underlying table. If you are doing code first, you need to update the class. EF is not using the stored procedure to build its model.

Comment: @SteveGreene I updated the stored procedure so database first. should the underlying table not be done by updating the database from Model? as per the docs

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716705(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Did you add the column "code" to the course table? I don't believe EF will go out and change that for you from within a stored proc.

Comment: @SteveGreene The column is in the database table..... When I run the query outside of the procedure my results show a Code column but I can't get it in the stored procedure resultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it....... After spending multiple hours searching the internet I found it. You have to go into your .edmx file - right click - model browser - expand scsmodel and then functionimports - find your stored procedures name - double click it - then click get column information - confirm your new column is appearing in the grid that appears - click update and hey presto! :)